# How to printf a variable length line in fixed length chunks?

Tags: bash, printing, newline, break

I need to to analyze (with `grep`) and print (with some formatting) the content of an 
app's log.

This log contains text data in variable length lines. What I need is, after some grepping, loop each line of this output and print it with a maximum fixed length of 50 characters. If a line is longer than 50 chars, it should print a newline and then continue with the rest in the following line and so on until the line is completed.

I tried to use `printf` to do this, but it's not working and I don't know why. It just outputs the lines in same fashion of `echo`, without any consideration about `printf` formatting, though the `\t` character (tab) works.

```
function printContext
{
    str="$1"
    log="$2"
    tmp="/tmp/deluge/$$"

    rm -f $tmp

    echo ""
    echo -e "\tLog entries for $str :"

    ln=$(grep -F "$str" "$log" &> "$tmp" ; cat "$tmp" | wc -l)

    if [ $ln -gt 0 ];
    then
            while read line
            do
                    printf "\t%50s\n" "$line"
            done < $tmp
    fi

}
```

What's wrong? I Know that I can make a substring routine to accomplish this task, but `printf` should be handy for stuff like this.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of:

```
printf "\t%50s\n" "$line"
```

use

```
printf "\t%.50s\n" "$line"
```

to truncate your line to 50 characters only.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about printf but seeing as how perl is installed everywhere, how about a simple 1 liner?

```
echo $ln | perl -ne ' while( m/.{1,50}/g ){ print "$&\n" } '
```

Comment: It works great, thank you.
I just put a \t in front of "$&" to indent it.
What about a similar solution to break the line at the nearest whitespace, instead of breaking exactly at 50th char, maybe in the middle of a word ?

Comment: Do you mean the nearest whitespace to the 50th character, either before or after? What if there is no whitespace at all? That would print the entire line

Answer (score 1):

Here's a clunky bash-only way to break the string into 50-character chunks

```
i=0
chars=50
while [[ -n "${y:$((chars*i)):$chars}" ]]; do
  printf "\t%s\n" "${y:$((chars*i)):$chars}"
  ((i++))
done
```